# Multiple “when”-conditions for a State

Tags: qml, state, qt-quick

Say I have following states:

```
State
{
    name: "red_state"
    when: color === "red"
},
State
{
    name: "blue_state"
    when: color === "blue"
},
State
{
    name: "square_state"
    when: shape === "square"
},
State
{
    name: "circle_state"
    when: shape === "circle"
},
State
{
   name: "blue_circle_state"
   when: color === "blue" && shape === "circle"
}
```

The “blue_circle_state” is never triggered, why is this? Is there a better way to have several conditions for a State?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is nothing wrong about having multiple conditions for a `State` in a `when`, the problem here is having `blue_state`, `circle_state` and `blue_circle_state` all evaluating to true at the  same time.
The [documentation about the when property of a State](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-state.html#when-prop) says :

> If multiple states in a group have when clauses that evaluate to true at the same time, the first matching state will be applied.

So when the color is blue and the shape is a circle, here only the `blue_state` will be active.

In your situation moving the more specific `blue_circle_state` at the beginning will solve your problem, but you still can't have multiple states active at the same time.

If you want to have a more advanced State Machine you can take a look at [The Declarative State Machine Framework](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlstatemachine.html).